# how do I replace string in django when displaying a value

Tags: django

I need to change any ' to \' when displaying a value in my template.

so eg {{ account.company_name|escapejs }} should replace any ' with \'

how do I do that ?

thanks
Thomas

** UPDATED CODE BASED ON COMMENTS BELOW **

My directory-structure is like this:

```
myapp/
  ....
  templatetags/
     __init__.py
     replace.py
```

Replace.py contains:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
from django.template import defaultfilters

@register.filter
@defaultfilters.stringfilter
def replace(value, args=","):
    try:
        old, new = args.split(',')
        return value.replace(old, new)
    except ValueError:
        return value
```

and in settings.py I have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ( 'myapp' )
```

In my template I try to load the customtag like this:

```
{% from replace load replace %}
```

and it is used like this

```
company_name='{{ account.company_name|escapejs|replace:"',\'" }}'
```

I then received this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'from'
```

and then changed to

```
{% load replace %} instead of {% from replace load replace %}
```

but then I get this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: 'replace' is not a valid tag library: Template library replace not found, tried google.appengine._internal.django.templatetags.replace
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`addslashes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#addslashes) built-in filter:

*From the documentation's example*:

`{{ value|addslashes }}`

If value is `"I'm using Django"`, the output will be `"I\'m using Django"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own filter:

```
@register.filter
@defaultfilters.stringfilter
def replace(value, args=","):
    try:
        old, new = args.split(',')
        return value.replace(old, new)
    except ValueError:
        return value
```

Then in your template:

```
{% load replace from mycustomtags %}

{{ account.company_name|escapejs|replace:"',\'" }}
```

(I haven't tested)

Comment: thanks, Where do I add the filter ? Sorry if this is a basic question

Comment: Documentation is your friend https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: and added it to my template, per your instructions, but I cannot get it to work. I am getting this error "TemplateSyntaxError: 'replace' is not a valid tag library: Template library replace not found, tried google.appengine._internal.django.templatetags.replace"

Comment: Add `from django.template import default filters`. Sorry that I missed that.

Comment: I am getting this error "TemplateSyntaxError: 'replace' is not a valid tag library: Template library replace not found, tried google.appengine._internal.django.templatetags.replace" I tried both {% load replace %} and {% load replace from mycustomtags %} at the top top of my template

Comment: `mycustomtags` was a dummy example. You should remove it. Then you can leave `{% load replace %}` or "replace" it with a more explicit `{% from replace load replace %}`. Be sure that your app is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`, otherwise Django will not look for your templatetags directory.

Comment: I still cannot get it to work. I outlined my code above. Can you spot what I am doing wrong ? Thanks

Comment: it seemed there is a built-in function to do what I wanted to do. Your help and time is appreciated